# Network and Share has become slow on the domain network

Tags: active-directory, switch, network-share

I have a very simple network set-up with 2 - 3 VLANs and the clients (around 15) on a domain network. The network and domain set-up is pretty simple as explained below;

- Two switches with a single link inter-connecting each other to carry VLANs
- Switch1 has two ports LAG'd from the server using LACP and is working fine
- Switch1 is connected to Switch2 using a copper cable, and trunk is configured
- Domain has two GPOs (1. for Network share map / 2. folder redirection)

Now the issue is that, PCs have become very slow and sluggish due to the network beeing slow as they are on a folder redirection GPO. This is also impacting the network share as well.

However, the physical (also the file server) running on Win 2012 R2, has two VMs (DC and APPS) can access, the network share like a charm using the network. I'm confused as to where I have missed out. It was all working fine until last three days ago and we carried out any changes in the network too. If anyone could advise me on this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally managed to fix the issue after a network/server restart. Further drilling down showed me that there was a VLAN loop between the switches and the server explorer process was hanging due to the symantec virus guard. Once I disabled and removed, it started working as usual.